# Is it really unsafe to use a GitHub self-hosted runner on a own public repository if actions are only triggered on push on certain protected branch?

Tags: github, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I was trying to set up a self-hosted runner to build and deploy my software on every commit to the master branch when I found out that using a self-hosted runner on a public repository introduces a security risk. [This is what the documentation says](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners#self-hosted-runner-security):

> #### Self-hosted runner security
>
> We recommend that you only use self-hosted runners with private
> repositories. This is because forks of your public repository can
> potentially run dangerous code on your self-hosted runner machine by
> creating a pull request that executes the code in a workflow.
>
> This is not an issue with GitHub-hosted runners because each
> GitHub-hosted runner is always a clean isolated virtual machine, and
> it is destroyed at the end of the job execution.
>
> Untrusted workflows running on your self-hosted runner pose
> significant security risks for your machine and network environment,
> especially if your machine persists its environment between jobs. Some
> of the risks include:
>
> - Malicious programs running on the machine.
> - Escaping the machine's runner sandbox.
> - Exposing access to the machine's network environment.
> - Persisting unwanted or dangerous data on the machine.

In another part of the documentation they [further explain the way in which this security risk might be exploited](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#hardening-for-self-hosted-runners):

> **GitHub-hosted** runners execute code within ephemeral and clean isolated virtual machines, meaning there is no way to persistently
> compromise this environment, or otherwise gain access to more
> information than was placed in this environment during the bootstrap
> process.
>
> **Self-hosted** runners for GitHub do not have guarantees around running in ephemeral clean virtual machines, and can be persistently
> compromised by untrusted code in a workflow.
>
> As a result, self-hosted runners should almost never be used for
> public repositories on GitHub, because any user can open pull requests
> against the repository and compromise the environment. Similarly, be
> cautious when using self-hosted runners on private or internal
> repositories, as anyone who can fork the repository and open a pull
> request (generally those with read access to the repository) are able
> to compromise the self-hosted runner environment, including gaining
> access to secrets and the GITHUB_TOKEN which, depending on its
> settings, can grant write access to the repository. Although workflows
> can control access to environment secrets by using environments and
> required reviews, these workflows are not run in an isolated
> environment and are still susceptible to the same risks when run on a
> self-hosted runner.
>
> Organization owners can disable the ability to create self-hosted
> runners at the repository level. For more information, see "Disabling
> or limiting GitHub Actions for your organization."
>
> When a self-hosted runner is defined at the organization or enterprise
> level, GitHub can schedule workflows from multiple repositories onto
> the same runner. Consequently, a security compromise of these
> environments can result in a wide impact. To help reduce the scope of
> a compromise, you can create boundaries by organizing your self-hosted
> runners into separate groups. You can restrict what organizations and
> repositories can access runner groups. For more information, see
> "Managing access to self-hosted runners using groups."

So, I thought that the only problem was that a runner is shared in an organization among the different repositories. I thought that the problem was that if one of the repositories of the organization has a colaborator that is malicius or that has been compromised he could create new workflows that run on self-hosted runners that can compromise the server where the runner is running.

Nevertheless, they say that the actual problem is that public repositories can receive pull requests from anyone and thus triggering jobs on the self-hosted runners on the organization.

So, in my organization I would like to have self-hosted runner on a public repository. However, there will be the following limitations:

- In this organization only people from the workplace (trusted users) will be added.
- All jobs will be triggered only on push.
- All jobs will be triggered only on the master branch
- The master branch will be protected and only writable by me and a small group of admins.
- There will be no mechanisms for an user that forks the repository to automerge a pull request such as using a third-party app that may automerge it.

Despite this limitations seem like a good idea to mitigate the risk, in the documentation they do not mention protecting branches and limiting the trigger of actions to these branches, they just talk about the possibility of a user forking and doing PR to the "vulnerable" repository. At least I did not find anything about it.

So, taking all this into account:

- Is still unsafe to use a self-hosted runner on a public repository?
- Can a public user that does not belong to the organization exploit this configuration to run non-authorized code in the self-hosted runner?
- Can someone explain how a malicius user not belonging to the organization would exploit this "vulnerable" repository by forking it and doing a PR?

Answer (score 1):

I think GitHub also runs the GitHub Actions workflows included in a PR. For example, one can create a GitHub Actions workflow to run on the pull_request event. When a pull request is created with this change, GitHub runs this new workflow as well?

Other than the threat scenario I have described above, the approach you have described should allow you to leverage self-hosted runners securely. The key would to make sure that these limitations continue to hold true as your GitHub organization grows with new repositories and new workflows. As there are no GitHub built-in solutions to enforce the limitations you have restricted in a consistent manner, it can be difficult to maintain them in the long term if your GitHub organization grows, specially if you have a de-centralized model where multiple individuals can introduce changes in your GitHub organization. Regular reviews, audits, and cautious granting of permissions might allevate some of these risks."

Comment: "For example, one can create a GitHub Actions workflow to run on the pull_request event. When a pull request is created with this change, GitHub runs this new workflow as well?" Exactly, that is my question. I think that this does not happen at all, so I do not understand why a self-hosted runner in a public repository should be a security vulnerability.

Comment: Also, it is true that in the long-therm this is going to be difficult to maintain, but I mitigated that by creating private repositories where I do not enforce this rules, so there is more freedom regarding GitHub Actions workflows management. If I need to expose the code to the public, I will just create a mirror in the same organization.